# Falling back maven dependency to more general classifier

Tags: maven, dependency-management, classification, maven-dependency-plugin

Maven was designed mainly to support Java. I would like however, to store in maven repository some platform-dependent artifacts.

I have 2 classifiers for that purpose:

- linux-**x86**
- linux-**x64**

Is it possible to define a dependency in such a way that if linux-**x64** artifact was not found, then Maven attempts to find linux-**x86**?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a deep look at the maven-nar-plugin https://github.com/duns/maven-nar-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way of doing this. In fact, it is really against Maven philosophy of being strict and straight about dependencies. Just imagine what compiler should do with such dependencies declaration? Should compile using `linux-x86` artifact or `linux-x64` artifact? I assume that the API/SPI of this modules is the same thing, but only you know that. Compiler needs specific classpath. And it is hard to say what does it mean in Maven that artifact cannot be found, because people can use different repositories and have different stuff in their local repos, so the build is not repeatable any more. Maven team currently assume as deprecated and advise against version ranges because of build unrepeatability and this is really "soft" thing compared to your idea.

My advice is to always release these two artifact (`linux-x86` and `linux-x64`) and release also the artifacts that depend on them using this 2 classifiers. That's the Maven way.